# Need guidance with segment control in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Since im still new to coding i need help figuring this out since i don't know how to get around it. I got a segment control to switch between standard, satellite and hybrid. But it is in the sidebarmenu and the class is tableviewcontroller. I need it to interact with the mapkit so i can get it to work when pressing the button. I already got a code but need guidance/help to get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Putting an image up here:

[image: Segment Control Issue]

Answer (score 1):

what exactly do you need? If you need explanation regarding the work you are doing... please follow this link.. https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial This site tries to explain everything in detail. Please vote the answer you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code you can see that you made an MKMapView by initializing it at a class scope with: `var mapView = MKMapView()`

What this did was allocate memory for the map and create it, but it is not on the screen. You will have to either add it via `Interface Builder` (the UI GUI on the left of your screenshot) or you will have to programmatically add it to the view.

[This is a tutorial on how to do it via IB, and it looks like this is something you already looked at judging by your code...](http://www.devfright.com/mkmapview-and-mkmapview-delegate-tutorial/)

It seems like you are brand new to writing code. You might want to consider taking a [free Computer Science 101 class by MIT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/introduction-to-computer-science/id341597455?mt=10)

Comment: I have another file for the "mapview" since the pic i showed up here was on the sidebarmenu. Check out this image: http://imgur.com/MHh4KUA